# Android - Calculator

Tags: android, calculator

I am new to android development and I am starting with a a simple app of calculator. Now I have a an activity which has all the number buttons and operators. What I want to achieve is if I press any numeric button, it should get displayed on a text field present in the same screen. My question here is that whether I should start a new activity after every press of any numeric keys on my app or it can be done within the same activity.?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and programming Android! Typically with questions on  SO, you need to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your attempt to code it and we would help you with any problems you have. Here's a good [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) from Google. Hint: the activity would be the calculator, you would just need buttons with OnClickListeners to do what you want (google it). Happy programming!

Comment: follow http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104931/Introduction-to-Android-development-TouchCalculato  also http://innovativenetsolutions.com/2013/01/calculator-app/

Comment: @GarySchreiner Not every question requires code, and in this case, although the OP does need to read the basics about activities, all the information necessary to answer the question is here.

Comment: @chrylis If the OP states he's new to Android and is making a statement about whether or not they should have a new activity for each button press on something that obviously should be a single activity with several events inside, it's probably safe to say he needs to read a few tutorials. I see nothing in my original comment that was invalid, didn't downvote him, and even offered a direction to go with his learning. See [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) #3.

Comment: @GarySchreiner Voting to close is fine, and your own comments were right on point. I was just responding to the MCVE comment (which appears to be from the canned SO comment).

Comment: @chrylis Actually, I wrote that out... I'm really bored on a Sunday night obviusly :). And I didn't vote to close, as I'm not big on discouraging new programmers, Just wanted to put him on the right track. MVCE comment was meant to push him into making an attempt at it and then asking for direction once he has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in same activity

set numeric value of button as its tag in xml or by code

by code:

```
Button1.setTag("1");
Button2.setTag("2"); etc...
```

set operator with +,-,* with respective number 100,200,300...

then implement onClickListener to your activity 
and
code  onClick() function of your activity as follows

```
public class Calc_Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

//your code

button1.setOnClickListenet(this);
button2.setOnClickListenet(this);
//do this to all your buttons

    @Override
public void onClick(View clickedView) 
{

    int tag=Integer.parseInt(clickedView.getTag.toString());
            if(tag<100)
    {
        numeric_number=tag;
                    //do remaining operations
    }
    else if(tag==100)
    {
      //operator "+"
              //do + operator work  

    }
    else if(tag==200)
    {
             //operator "-"
     // do - operator work  
    }
            //continue for other operators

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button click add this

`myText.setText(myText.getText() + " 9");`

9 is the number from button with number 9.

Comment: @user3627182 if this is the answer you looking for, you may thick it as the correct answer :)

Comment: One more thing. Correct me if I am wrong . For example: If I want to add 19 to 17, so i first press '1' and then '7'. Later i need to press a '+' , '1' and '9'. Since all the caculators have a display screen, I also want to show the user what exactly he/she is typing on a display screen. For this I am using a Edit Box. Now as soon as I press '1' , it will come to display screen as suggested by you in your answer.  After this he presses '7', so what I want is that this '7' must be appended to already typed '1' (of course, on the right side) , so that it becomes '17'.So continued...

Comment: So do we need to convert this '17' into String text and then display it on the Edit box ??

Comment: just use my same approach by using this `myText.setText(myText.getText() + " 9");`  you are getting the text that inside of your edittext and append the new one to it. that simple.